# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)

Tags: errors, packages, input-encodings

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.622 \BDBL {}Grozdanić
, S.%
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
Underfull \vbox (badness 1810) has occurred while \output is active []
[48
```

Comment: Please show a MWE (Minimal, Working Example) with which we can reproduce the problem .  Which LaTeX program (and version) are you trying to run?

Comment: 301 is the acute accent. Retype the ć so that you get a real glyph and not a c + combining accent.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wonder if we should pre-define the combining accents to give a more specific error that says exactly that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not a bad idea.

Comment: Related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369940/sanitize-u301-infection-and-others-in-references