# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ̀ (U+300) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

I am struggling understanding how to solve this error:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ̀ (U+300)  (inputenc)  not set up
> for use with LaTeX.

I have seen this related [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406416/how-to-solve-the-package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-not-set-up-for-use-with-l), but the problem is that I have no idea where I have used this character and it seems I can't find it with find command.

Comment: Add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0300}{HEREHEREHERE}` to your document, then you should be able to find it.

Comment: Use `uconv`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369940/sanitize-u301-infection-and-others-in-references)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this really point me to the solution/answer to the problem. I think that could be elaborated to an answer for the other user. Thanks a lot, I lost some hours finding the solution until your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

U+0300 is a combining grave accent.  PDFTeX and the 8-bit `inputenc` package cannot handle combining Unicode characters, only precomposed characters (NFC form).

The following MWE will reproduce your bug, if compiled in PDFTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
à
\end{document}
```

This is because à is in decomposed form (U+0061 U+0300) instead of the NFC form, à (U+00E0).  This is just one example, and there are several other places it could appear.  (The most-famous example in English probably is Shakespare’s use of “punishèd.”)

If you compile with LuaLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX, the engine will understand the combining character, but your 8-bit font will not contain it, so it will not display.  The `\tracinglostchars=2` line will at least give you a warning message about it.

Since the code I gave would never have compiled, though, it’s not likely that your old document has anything like that in it.  Some users report that `\'{\i}` in their bibliographies causes this bug.  In old versions of TeX, you needed to superimpose accents on a dotless `ı`, not over an `i` with a dot.  That is no longer necessary, as `\'{i}` will be defined as a text composite.

This gives you the following options:

#### Use a Unicode Engine

If you remove the 8-bit font packages such as `fontenc` and `inputenc`, and compile with LuaTeX or XeTeX, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
à
\end{document}
```

#### Convert to Precomposed Characters

I happen to have written [a little program](https://github.com/Davislor/normal-ha) that normalizes UTF-8 input to NFC form, or you can do a search-and-replace.

This works, because it contains no combining characters, only precomposed characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
à
\end{document}
```

#### Use Accent Macros

If you must use PDFTeX, and there is no precomposed character for the the grapheme you want, you could write it as

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\`{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried but I can't find any à in my bibliography or chapters. An I see that other characters like è é are properly rendered

Comment: In fact, it was due to the use of ```{\`\i}``` that was probably the result of some exportation of the bibliography reference. 

I replaced this with ```\`{i}``` and this solved the issue.

Comment: @GM That’s good. In some older versions of LaTeX, it was necessary to superimpose accents on a dotless `i`, and in theory that should still work. Today, though, i with a grave accent should be declared as a text composite.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Maybe we could add this to your answer for the other users that might look for à while is due to this old convention.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was due to \'\i that was the correct way to do it "in earlier times".